# Flutter : Let the Image in ListViewBuilder overflow on new line

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a ListView Builder widget where I put some images in (cards pictures), but some card pictures hit the max width of the screen. Lets say I have 10 item (pictures) and 2 of them is not visible. I can't see.

Issue : [Issue Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBUe3.png)

I want to have it like this:

- [PICTURE][PICTURE][PICTURE][PICTURE][PICTURE][PICTURE][PICTURE]-
  -[PICTURE][PICTURE][PICTURE][PICTURE][PICTURE]

Heres my code : ( I tried Wrap widget and it didn't work)

```
Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    colour: Colors.green,
                    cardChild: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: cardBrain.mycards.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) => Wrap(
                        direction: Axis.vertical,
                        children: [
                          Image(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 55,
                            image: AssetImage(
                              '${cardBrain.mycards[i].image}',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read post rules first. And use

```
Wrap( alignment: WrapAlignment.center,)
```

instead of

```
Wrap(direction: Axis.vertical,)
```